# Add color to div based on dynamic data in ng-repeat

Tags: css, angularjs, bootstrap-4

I am trying to do a table with three columns, and n number of rows. and every alternate row should have a different background color. The data I have is dynamic. I am able to get the row and columns, but not sure how to do background color.

I have tried doing it with DIV and td of table, when I do td its all coming in a single row.

```
model.names = ['a','b','c','s','s','ww','ee','rrgf','fdf','dfdf','dfdf','ffd'];
```

```
<div class="col-xs-12" data-ng-if="model.showlist==true">
<div class="col-xs-4 myClass" data-ng-repeat="x in model.names">
{{x}}
</div>
</div>
```

with this code I am getting my desired table but I am confused on How to do styling. I have also tried this.

```
<table><tr>
<td class="col-xs-4 myClass" data-ng-repeat="x in model.names">
{{x}} </td>
</tr></table>
```

expected o/p will be

```
a b c (background color -grey)
a s ww
ee rrgf fdf (background color -grey)
dfdf dfdf ffd
```

Actual is this when doing with DIV (format is correct but don't know how to do color)

```
a b c 
a s ww
ee rrgf fdf 
dfdf dfdf ffd
```

Actual is this when doing with table

```
a b c a s ww ee rrgf fdf dfdf dfdf ffd
```

Comment: Check the below snippet and let me know if it works as per your requirement !!

Comment: Please check the below snippet. Updated the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<div class="col-xs-4" ng-class='{"grey-color": ($index/3) % 2 < 1}' data-ng-repeat="x in model.names">
  {{x}}
</div>
```

css

```
.grey-color {
    background-color: grey;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 '<table>
<tr>
<td data-ng-repeat="x in model.names" ng-class="{'grayColor': x.names == 'a' ||'grayColor': x.names == 'b' || 'grayColor': x.names == 'c'">
{{x}} 
</td>
</tr></table>'
```

css:- `.grayColor{ background-color:gray}`

Answer (score 0):

It should be in this way `tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #CCC}` to make your odd table row bg-color to be gray.

To get the data in each row `ng-repeat` should be in `tr`

```
    <table>
      <tr data-ng-repeat="x in model.names">
        <td class="col-xs-4 myClass">
          {{x}} </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

CSS

```
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: gray}
```

Below is the working snippet for the same

```js
(function() {
  angular.module("myApp", []).controller('test', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.rules = ['a', 'b', 'c', 's', 'ww', 'ee', 'rrgf', 'fdf', 'dfdf', 'ffd','ddw','qer'];
    const chunk =
      (size, xs) =>
      xs.reduce(
        (segments, _, index) =>
        index % size === 0 ?
        [...segments, xs.slice(index, index + size)] :
        segments, []
      );

    $scope.new = chunk(3, $scope.rules);
  }]);
}());
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.6" data-semver="1.6.6" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="test">
    <table>
        <tr>
          <th>column 1</th>
          <th>column 2</th>
          <th>column 3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="x in new">
          <td>
            <h1>{{x[0]}}</h1>
          </td>
          <td>
            <h1>{{x[1]}}</h1>
          </td>
          <td>
            <h1>{{x[2]}}</h1>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi Manoj, Thank you for this!! I tried this, but I need three columns for each row